# Couldn't remount RDWR because of unprocessed orphan inode list in VirtualBox VM

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I have been using ubuntu 14.x from windows using virtual box.but suddenly ubuntu instance stopped working and when i start the virtual machine using vagrant up command it is saying

> Couldn't remount RDWR because of unprocessed orphan inode list.

Does anyone knows how to boot virtual machine and solve mounting issue.?

Comment: Take a look at: https://serverfault.com/questions/278198/how-to-clean-up-an-unprocessed-orphan-inode-list

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same issue on an AWS EC2 machine. To complicate the resolution, the volume that was affected was the root volume of the EC2 instance. Hence the device was failing to boot and SSH was also not possible to the instance.

The following steps helped me resolve the issue:

1. Detach the volume from the EC2 instance.
2. Configure a new EC2 instance using the same AMI and in the same AZ as that of the old one.
3. Attach the volume (detached in Step 1) to the new instance.
4. Execute the following commands:

```
# Switch to Root user:
sudo -i

# Identify the device Filesystem name and save it as a variable:
lsblk
rescuedev=/dev/xvdf1    # Mention the right Filesystem for the particular volume.

# Use /mnt as the mount point:
rescuemnt=/mnt
mkdir -p $rescuemnt
mount $rescuedev $rescuemnt

# Mount special file systems and change the root directory (chroot) to the newly mounted file system:
for i in proc sys dev run; do mount --bind /$i $rescuemnt/$i ; done
chroot $rescuemnt

# Download, install and execute EC2Rescue tool for Linux to fix the issues: 
curl -O https://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2rescuelinux/ec2rl.tgz
tar -xf ec2rl.tgz
cd ec2rl-<version_number>
./ec2rl run
cat /var/tmp/ec2rl/*/Main.log | more
./ec2rl run --remediate

# Switch back from the Root user and unmount the volume:
exit
umount $rescuemnt/{proc,sys,dev,run,}
```

5. Shut down the EC2 instance and detach the volume.
6. Attach the volume to the original instance and start the EC2 instance.